# Why K8S don't support PreStart Hook

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

As we know, k8s supports `postStart` and `preStop` lifecycle hook, but in most cases what we need is actually `preStart`.

Is there any reason not implementing the `preStart` hook?

Comment: There are init containers

Comment: What l need is to do something before the main container started..

Comment: e.g. What if l want to create a linux user dynamically before the main container started

Comment: Before it started - you cannot do anything inside it, because it's not started.

Comment: Containers are supposed to be immutable. That's the theory anyway. It might be that what you're doing is particularly not what they want to support as a pattern.

Going outside the box - maybe you can write a script that does the work and create your own container image. Pump any variables in as environment variables or configmaps?

Answer (score 3):

look at [Init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to do preStart task.

### Note:

In fact there is already a PR requested to introduce prestart and postStart hooks in pod lifecycle. It has been pending since 2014 and not much progress is seen.
follow the link -> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/140

Comment: What l need is to do something before the main container started..

Comment: e.g. What if l want to create a linux user dynamically before the main container started

Comment: cant it be done using a startup script before the container process is started?

Comment: My scenary is to dynamically insert the command to create a user based on the user's input (e.g.username), l actually don't know what the real command is, so l cannot hack it by inserting a script at the beginning of the Command

Comment: And l am actually writing a controller, l want to hijack the pod creation event and insert
a command before the main pod command. But it seems difficult to do that because in some cases user may not have Command in pod YAML and it will use the default Dockerfile entrypoint & cmd as Command, so cannot hack it. So what l need is a `PreStart` hook... Is there any thought on it ?

Comment: There is already a PR opened to introduce prestart hook. but not much progress is made. added the link in response. you can do followup in github issue page.

Comment: Thanks.. But l actually opened one issue in github but no one seems to reply till now 